# Retrieving camera orientation from DLT parameters

Tags: image-processing, camera, projection, camera-calibration

I currently have 12 DLT parameters to map 3D points to 2D pixels, the projection/conversion works nicely.

Now, I am able to retrieve the camera position from the parameters using equation [25] from [Kwon3D](http://www.kwon3d.com/theory/dlt/dlt.html). However, I could not find the formula to derive the actual **orientation** of the camera.

I can calculate the principal point (in 2D pixel space, using the same website). I suspect I need to transform this to 3D object space to get the camera gaze direction. Also the normal of the image plane can be used, but I also don't know how that can be calculated. Surely (hopefully) there is an easier solution and any help would be really appreciated.

As the 12 DLT parameters basically comprise the camera matrix, it should be possible..

Answer (score 1):

I used the same website as a guide and was struggling with the same problem.
The important thing that was missing for me (maybe it is obvious for others) is that D at equation 26 is the distance between the camera and the principal point in object space units. du and dv (should almost be the same) are the distance in image units (probably pixels). So D is basically d from equation 6 or earlier. I don't know why they use a capital D suddenly without mentioning or explaining it.

To calculate the principal point in object space coordinates we can use equation 3. u-u0 and v-v0 are zero. c is equal to one and D can the calculated. We can rearrange the equation to give the x, y, and z coordinates in object space units for the principal point.

This is what it would look like in Matlab:
[x; y; z]=inv(T)*[0; 0; D]+[x0; y0; z0]